# Original concentration calculation homework

Tags: homework, inorganic-chemistry, ions, concentration, precipitation

A student performs the following gravimetric analysis of iron ions in a water system
$$\ce{Fe^2+  (aq) + CO3^2-  (aq) <=> FeCO3 (s)}$$
If this student used excess carbonate and obtained the following data, what was the original concentration in moles/L) of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ in the water sample?

Total Volume of Solution: 100.00 mL

Mass of $\ce{FeCO3}$ collected: 23.758 grams.

Change 100 ml to 0.1 liters $x + 115.583 = 23.758 \times 0.1 = 0.02~\mathrm{l}$
- would this be how you solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, just a heads up: in order to make a new paragraph, you have to make two line breaks after a paragraph. Regarding your solution itself, the first thing I noticed is that you converted mL to L wrongly. Apart from that I'm afraid you'll have to make it a little clearer what you are trying to say. What does $x$ represent? Where does 11.583 come from?

Comment: Trying to find the original concentration of the equation I used M1V1 = M2V2

Comment: liters should be .1 liters   M1 is the molar mass of FeCO3 = 115.853g  X V1 = 23.758g X .1 litter = .02 liters - would this be the original concentration

Answer (score 2):

The mass of $\ce{FeCO3}$ is given as $m_{\ce{FeCO3}}=23.758\ \mathrm g$.

You already found that the molar mass of $\ce{FeCO3}$ is $M_{\ce{FeCO3}}=115.85\ \mathrm{g\ mol^{-1}}$.

For a pure sample, molar mass $M$ is defined as
$$M=\frac mn$$
where $m$ is mass and $n$ is amount of substance.
Thus, the amount of $\ce{FeCO3}$ can be calculated as follows:
$$\begin{align}n_{\ce{FeCO3}}&=\frac {m_{\ce{FeCO3}}}{M_{\ce{FeCO3}}}\\[6pt]
&=\frac {23.758\ \mathrm g}{115.85\ \mathrm{g\ mol^{-1}}}
\end{align}$$

The chemical equation
$$\ce{Fe^2+ + CO3^2- <=> FeCO3}$$
indicates that $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ yields $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{FeCO3}$. Therefore, 
$$n_{\ce{Fe^2+}}=n_{\ce{FeCO3}}$$

The volume of the solution is given as $V=100.00\ \mathrm{ml}=0.10000\ \mathrm l$.

The concentration $c$ is defined as
$$c=\frac nV$$
where $n$ is amount of substance and $V$ is the volume of the solution.
Thus, the concentration of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ can be calculated as follows:
$$\begin{align}c_{\ce{Fe^2+}}&=\frac {n_{\ce{Fe^2+}}}V\\[6pt]
&=\frac {n_{\ce{Fe^2+}}}{0.10000\ \mathrm l}\end{align}$$

Comment: I consider this to be the blueprint of how to answer [tag:homework] questions!